# Xamarin.MacOS app oAuth2 login sample code

Tags: xamarin.mac

Is there any sample code on how to implement oAuth2 login for Google and Facebook for Xamarin.Mac app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for answer user SimpleAuth [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clancey.SimpleAuth/):

```cs
var api = new FacebookApi("facebook", clientid,clientsecret);
SimpleAuth.Account response = await api.Authenticate();
```